# What's meaning of "accumulation" for a collection of open sets of $X$?

Tags: general-topology, terminology

Let $X$ be a topological space and $\xi=\{V_n: n\in\omega\}$ is a collection of open sets of $X$.

If one say $z$ is an accumulation point for the sequence $\xi=\{V_n: n\in\omega\}$. What's meaning of "accumulation" for a collection of open sets of $X$?

Thanks ahead.

Comment: $z\in X$ such that $\xi$ is not locally finite at $z$.

Comment: @M.sina: Do you sure?

Comment: See: A.V. Arhangel'skii, *On a theorem of W.W. Comfort and K.A. Ross*, Comment.Math.Univ.Carolin. 40,1 (1999)133–151; [dml.cz](http://dml.cz/dmlcz/119068), p134.

May be defined differently in different references.

Comment: I agree with @M.Sina (who could turn that reference into an answer); that’s the most likely meaning, especially in the context of the papers that I know you’ve been reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Getting this off the Unanswered list.)

The most likely meaning is that $\xi$ is not locally finite at $z$, i.e., that every nbhd of $z$ intersects infinitely many of the sets $V_n$.